# how to reference conditional variables in custom block in serverless.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to deploy a serverless app that their variables depend on different environments.
so far I only need to modify the `customDomain` in the `custom` block based on the environment:

```
custom:
    domainName: my-domain.example.com
    certificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123123123:certificate/acm-id-based-on-env
```

I would like to set domainName and certificateArn depending on whether I call serverless deploy using:

```
serverless deploy --stage dev <<--- use some vars for domainName and certficiateArn
serverless deploy --stage prod <<--- use different vars for domainName and certificateArn
```

it seems in the resources block I should be allowed to do something like:

```
resources:
  Mappings:
    config:
      dev:
        domain_name: dev-domain.example.com 
        acm_arn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123123123:certificate/prod-id
      prod:
        domain_name: prod-domain.other-domain.com
          acm_arn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123123123:certificate/dev-id
```

but I don't know how to reference these in the custom block, nor even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `resources` you specify a CloudFormation template, unless you want to use it in CloudFormation that's not where it should go.

I guess you want to add the variables as environment variables in your functions, this is the most common approach in Serverless Framework:

```yaml
custom:
  domain_name:
    dev: dev-domain.example.com
    prod: prod-domain.other-domain.com
  acm_arn:
    dev: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123123123:certificate/dev-id
    prod: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:123123123:certificate/prod-id
...
provider:
  ...
  environment:
    DOMAIN_NAME: ${self:custom.domain_name.${self:provider.stage}}
    ACM_ARN: ${self:custom.acm_arn.${self:provider.stage}}
```

You add them in `custom` for each stage and then you reference and insert them in the `environment` section.

Comment: It works, but I think you have a typo in the answer, as `${self:provider.stage}` should actually be `${opt:stage}` (at least that's how got it to work)